# what makes the baby rabbit get swollen stomach and at what stage do one separate them from their mother?

Tags: death

am having seventeen baby rabbit and two left now. I have lost fifteen. please what is the course?

Comment: Please elaborate with sequence of events, cause of death or symptoms, behavioural information and diet, and anything else you think may be relevant. Without it the only answer you can get from us "Get to a vet". Granted, even with all the information the answer will probably still be "get to a vet"

Comment: Part of this question is duplicate of the existing that I have closed it as a duplicate of.  There is not enough information to begin addressing the rest of the question. You may want to look through our existing posts, starting with the ones on [rabbit breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbits+breeding)